# Move a movieclip at each click

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I'd like to create a mini game in my game. The aim of the mini game would be : 
To push a cow in a truck by clicking quickly with the mouse. If you're not fast enough, the cow is returning to its original point.

So, I think I must create the cow movieclip and indicate coordinate x something and y something.

Then tell the code that everytime the player click, the movieclip goes y +1.

BUT, every 0.5 seconds the movielcip goes  y-2 (unless it's at his original coordinates).

And tells the code that, when the cow movieclip is at x.somethingelse and y.somethingelse, the puzzle is complete.

Now..last but not least... How I can I do that ?

Would it be something like this ? :

```
cow = new cowMovieclip;
addchild(cow);
cow.x = 0;
cow.y = 0;

cow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, push, false, 0, true);

public function push(e:MouseEvent):void{
// I don't think it's like that
cow.x = +1;
cow.y = +1;
}

if (cow.y = 30){
allPuzzles.room.cowPushed = true;
}
```

And there's the code that tells the cow to goes -1 if the player don't click, but I don't know at all how to put this...

So, nothing is working with this code, so I assume I've done lot of mistakes.

Can you help me ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: see this [how can i continuously decrease a number in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512604/how-can-i-continuously-decrease-a-number-in-as3) What you need is either a Timer or an ENTER_FRAME event listener that gets fired on every frame in your movie.

Comment: And, `if (cow.y == 30)` and `cow.y+=1;` (or `cow.y ++;`). Also, do read something about correct syntax in AS3, it follows C style, so reading basics on syntax in C, C++ or C# should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

//class names should be capitalized, fix the symbol name in your library
var cow:MovieClip = new CowMovieClip(); 
addChild(cow);
cow.x = 0;
cow.y = 0;
cow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, push, false, 0, true);

var timer:Timer = new Timer(500);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveCowBack);
timer.start();

function push(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    cow.x += 1;
    cow.y += 1;

    //once the cow's y position has reached or exceeded 30, you no longer want the timer to move it back
    if (cow.y >= 30)
    {
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveCowBack);
        allPuzzles.room.cowPushed = true;
    }
}

function moveCowBack(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    // you don't want the cow to leave the screen, so only move it if the y position is >= 2
    if(cow.y >= 2)
    {
        cow.y -= 2;
    }
}
```